# Proving a series of a subsequence converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(a_{n})$ be an unbounded sequence. Prove that there exists a subsequence $(a_{nk})$ such that
$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a_{nk}}$ converges absolutely.

I've been trying to prove this but the standard tests for converges do not work as there is no function for he subsequence. In addition, how can we create a subsequence that would be able to work with the original sequence $a_{n}$ being unbounded? Usually the requirement is for the sequence to be bounded.

Comment: Choose $ a_{n_k} $ such that $ a_{n_k} >k^2$.

Comment: Can you show that you can always choose $a_{n_{k+1}} \geq 2 a_{n_k}$ for each $k$?  This *can't* work for a bounded sequence (because the reciprocals won't go to zero, so the series can't converge).

Answer (score 3):

If $a_{n}$ is unbounded, it means that $\forall C>0$, it exists $\bar n\in\mathbb N$ such that $|a_{\bar n}|>C$. In particular, it is easy to prove that if $(a_{n})_{n>0}$ is unbounded, then $(a_{n})_{n>k}$ is unbounded, too, $\forall k\in\mathbb N$.

Consider a sequence $C_{k}$ such that $\sum 1/C_{k}<+\infty$ (for example $C_{k}=k^2$). Define $$n_{k}:=\min\{n>n_{k-1}\ \text{such that}\ |a_{n}|>C_{k}\},$$
which is well defined by the remarks done above. It follows that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{|a_{n_{k}}|}\le\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{C_{k}}<+\infty,$$
that is series converges absolutely.